# Plotting time series in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I'm new in R.
I have a set of daily data in this link [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1hl1dss80nhv2dp/sample.csv?dl=0). My code is:

```
#plotting CLOSE
plot.ts(datatest$CLOSE,ylab="Close")
```

And this is result:

[image: [Graph][2].]

Problem is the `xlab`, I would like to show `DATE` variable, but it seems to show the order of `CLOSE` variable. I also try out other commands like `ggplot`, `xyplot` etc. but they require converting to `data.frame` and it's so hard to me.

I would be grateful for some guidance on how to get `DATE` variable in the Graph.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, I can modify it by Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will do it:

```
# load data:
theData = read.csv2(file = "sample.csv",header = TRUE,
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE,sep = ",",
                    colClasses = c("character",rep("numeric",5)),dec=".")

# We want to plot a custom x-axis, so stop the default
# x-axis being drawn usign xaxt="n":
plot(theData$CLOSE,type="l",xaxt="n")

# Lets say you want to put a date label in 8 different locations:
locations = floor(seq(from=1,to=nrow(theData),by=nrow(theData)/8))

# Now draw the x-axis on your plot like this:
axis(side = 1, at = locations, labels=theData$DATE[locations],las=2)
```

In the above, `side=1` means drawing the axis at the bottom. `at=locations` means we want to show tick labels at the locations given in the locations vector we created earlier. `labels=theData$DATE[locations]` provides the labels we want to place at the locations where we are putting a label. `las=2` means you want to rotate the tick labels. Try `las=1` as well for a different rotation.

However, those dates are kind of long, so you may want to create smaller dates like this:

```
# Convert your long dates to smaller dates like YYYY-MM-DD, and stick
# the results to the end of your data frame.
theData = cbind(theData,
                "FormattedDate"=as.Date(theData$DATE,"%A, %B %e, %Y"))

# Replot and use your smaller dates. (ces.axis=0.8 makes
# the font smaller)
plot(theData$CLOSE,type="l",xaxt="n")
axis(side = 1, at = locations,
     labels=theData$FormattedDate[locations],las=1,cex.axis=0.8)
```

Finally, you can also use some nice time series packages to create much nicer plots easily:

```
install.packages("xts")
library(xts)
xtsData = xts(theData[,"OPEN"],order.by = theData[,"FormattedDate"])
plot.zoo(xtsData)
# or
plot.xts(xtsData)
```

[image: Left is with zoo. Right is with xts]

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
dataset$DATE<-.as.POSIXct(dataset$DATE)
```

Comment: This is R message
`datatest$DATE=as.POSIXct(datatest$DATE)
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

Comment: if I changed into Short date format in file csv, then how I add DATE variable into Graph of time series?

Answer (score 1):

```
   dataset$DATE <- as.Date(dataset$DATE, format = "%A, %B %d, %Y")
```

- %A - long weekday
- %B - Full month name
- %d - two digit date
- %Y - four digit year